# When an object is locked, and this object is replaced, is the lock maintained?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have this java code:

```
synchronized(someObject)
{
    someObject = new SomeObject();
    someObject.doSomething();
}
```

Is the instance of SomeObject still locked by the time doSomething() is called on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread will still own the monitor for the *original* value of `someObject` until the end of the synchronized block. If you imagine that there were two methods, `Monitor.enter(Object)` and `Monitor.exit(Object)` then the synchronized block would act something like:

```
SomeObject tmp = someObject;
Monitor.enter(tmp);
try
{
    someObject = new SomeObject();
    someObject.doSomething();
}
finally
{
    Monitor.exit(tmp);
}
```

From [section 14.19 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.19):

> A synchronized statement is executed by first evaluating the Expression.
>
> If evaluation of the Expression completes abruptly for some reason, then the synchronized statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>
> Otherwise, if the value of the Expression is null, a NullPointerException is thrown.
>
> Otherwise, let the non-null value of the Expression be V. The executing thread locks the lock associated with V. Then the Block is executed. If execution of the Block completes normally, then the lock is unlocked and the synchronized statement completes normally. If execution of the Block completes abruptly for any reason, then the lock is unlocked and the synchronized statement then completes abruptly for the same reason.

Note how the evaluation only occurs once.

Comment: But the `someObject` is being reconstructed.Isn't the previous object GCd?I don't understand how the thread will still hold the lock for an object out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for the writeout :) @user384706: maybe the fact that the thread is holding the lock on that object is seen by the garbage collector as there still being references to that object present?

Comment: @user384706: Just because `someObject` no longer refers to it doesn't mean it's been garbage collected... and in fact it can't be, during that block.

Answer (score 3):

The lock applies to an object, not a variable. After `someObject = new SomeObject();` the variable `someObject` references a new object, the lock is still on the old one.

Bye and bye very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the **previous** instance of **someObject** is locked and your **new** instance is not locked.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the difference between synchronized **methods** and synchronized **statements**.

Take a look at this page which explains it pretty well: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: I just read a whole book about concurrency ;) This was the only thing I was wondering about